# Jquery: Accessing values of multiDimensional JSON object and assign in a form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working with the huge Multidimensional JSON Objects where the user will submit the values in the form fields, then these values will be Stored in the database in JSON format like String

**Example of JSON:**

```
{
  "Cat": {
    "enabled": false,
    "Color": "#994c4c"
    "height":10,
    "eye": "blue",
  },
  "Dog": {
    "enabled": true,
    "typeOf": {
      "breed": "Affenpinscher"
    }
  },
  "Elephant": {
    "enabled": true,
    "food": {
      "type": {
        "fruits": true,
      }
    }
  }
}
 ........... continues...
```

User can create n number of JSON Strings like above with new properties and it will be stored in the Database

So when the user Select the required JSON String from Database, i parse the string into JSON Objects in Jquery,

But my biggest Problem is, I need to loop over these huge JSON Objects and retrieve the values from those Objects and i need to assign it in respective form fields

**Examples of my From Fields:**

```
<select id="CatEnabled">
<option value="true">TRUE<option>
<option value="false">FALSE<option>
</select>

<input type="number" id="CatHeigt" min="20"/>

<input type="text" id="DogTypeOfBreed"/>

<select id="ElephantFoodTypeFruits">
<option value="true">TRUE<option>
<option value="false">FALSE<option>
</select>
```

My form fields will look something like the above, As My form field also contains huge number of fields almost more than 500+ fields,

i am retrieving the JSON Objects something like this

```
            $.each(JSON.parse(cmsg), function (key, value) {
              if(key=="cat")
                 CatHeigt.val(value.height);
        });
```

the above for each loop is just a sample, i will loop inside a loop to get the values of JSON, as per my JSON Structure

But only thing i need a simple Loop function to retrieve all the values and i need to assign it in all the respective form fields, i dont need something like this CatHeigt.val(value.height); because this process takes me too long for assigning all the 500+ form fields, instead i need simple solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using a *PascalCased* string of your object path as element `id`s. It would be easier if you could use a delimited string.

Having done that, you can (1) split the string into an array based on that delimiter, (2) iterate that array and checking each item if it is an object property of your json object, (3) if found, assign that property to the object itself for the next iteration, (4) return the last object, (5) use that object value to assign to your form elements by iterating them as well.

***Note***: You have to be consistent in naming your elements, variables and properties. In your code as posted in the question, there is no consistency. For the example below, I have converting everything to lower case to normalize it. For all practical purposes, you will have to relook at that.

***This snippet*** will make it clear to you:

```js
var jsonString = '{"Cat": {"enabled": false, "Color": "#994c4c", "height":10, "eye": "blue" }, "Dog": { "enabled": true, "typeOf": {"breed": "Affenpinscher"}},"Elephant": {"enabled": true, "food": {"type": {"fruits": true}}}}';

var json = JSON.parse(jsonString.toLowerCase()); /* converted to lowercase */

function getProp(obj, str) {
    var arr = str.toLowerCase().split('-'); // splitting on delimiter 
    arr.forEach(function(item, idx) {       // iterate the split array 
        if (item in obj) obj = obj[item];   // if item is in object, assign this prop
        else return;                        // to the object. otherwise continue
    });                     
    return obj;                             // return the found prop as current obj
}

var $elems = $("input, select");            // jQuery set of all your elements
$elems.each(function() {                    // iterate this set of elements
    var id = this.id, 
        propValue = getProp(json, id);      // get the property by passing json and id
    $(this).val(propValue.toString());      // set the retreived property as val 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Cat-Enabled">
    <option value="true">TRUE</option>
    <option value="false">FALSE</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<input type="number" id="Cat-Height" min="20"/>
<input type="text" id="Dog-TypeOf-Breed"/>
<br /><br />
<select id="Elephant-Food-Type-Fruits">
    <option value="true">TRUE</option>
    <option value="false">FALSE</option>
</select>
```

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5ybu7nt3/1/***

.

Comment: thats amazing abhitalks, but now i need to change the Id name for all 500+ fields, Thank you so much Abhitalks

Comment: @musthafa: It is possible to parse existing PascalCase as well, (you have to find the occurrence of uppercase letters and then make an array out of it). Moreover as I mentioned, naming is not consistent in your case e.g. `typeOf` property will then fail !!! It is always better to stick to conventions and keep naming consistent. It will help save you a lot of trouble. Wish you good luck!

Comment: Thats great abhi here after i ll follow the better coding standard